# how to change the hsv of texture in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

Im having a three dimensional array of rgba texture and im displaying it on my viewport.

how can i change the color Hue, Saturation and value by input user gave . im new to opengl so need guidance to change the HSV according to user selection .

Comment: Another near-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11458552/179910.

Comment: How nice! Have to try that.

Comment: Quetzalcoat .. thx i made it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/) and look at the implementation in gtx/color_space.inl of these functions

```
template<typename valType >
detail::tvec3< valType >    hsvColor (detail::tvec3< valType > const &rgbValue)

template<typename valType >
detail::tvec3< valType >    rgbColor (detail::tvec3< valType > const &hsvValue)
```

prototyped in [gtx/color_space.hpp](http://glm.g-truc.net/api-0.9.4/a00164.html)