# formation of image

Tags: colors

how to make an image(of 510*510) with red , green ,bue in upper row and cyan magenta and yellow in lower row in matlab  with equal portion for all.

Comment: For 120 degrees, can't you just swap r, g, and b?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8510751/5987 for rotating RGB hues directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but I *think* I know what you are asking for. The hue channel of an HSV image is usually thought of as ranging from 0 to 360 degrees, since it is a [cylindrical-coordinate representation of points in an RGB color model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). However, the values of the hue channel are likely ranging from 0 to 1 for your image, which is what you get as output from the function [RGB2HSV](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html), if that's what you used to get your HSV map.

So, if you want to shift your hues by 120 degrees, you would have to shift your range by 1/3. In other words, values ranging from 0 to 1/3 should be changed to range from 1/3 to 2/3, assuming a positive shift of 120 degrees. You can achieve this with the [REM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rem.html) function like so:

```
H = rem(H + 1/3, 1);
```

For a negative shift of 120 degrees, you can just apply an equivalent positive shift of 240 degrees, like so:

```
H = rem(H + 2/3, 1);
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. Given the comment by @Rabeel, I suspect this may be a Matlab-for-beginner exercise about reordering an array, though.

Answer (score 2):

For a poor-man's version of @gnovice's answer, I suggest simply swapping the R,G, and B channels, as suggested by @JasonD

Say you have a n-by-m-by-3 RGB image stored in an array `img`. Then, you shift the channels as follows

```
shiftedImg = img(:,:,[2 3 1]);
```

or

```
shiftedImg = img(:,:,[3 1 2]);
```

Comment: @Rabeel: my solution does not use builtin functions at all. Unless you count accessing array elements as a builtin function, in which case you won't be able to use Matlab at all.